# Will my question show up in Microsoft Teams stack overflow connector?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to get the stack overflow connector to work in Microsoft Teams. Will this question show up?

**Edit:**
Sometimes it is necessary to demonstrate an entire workflow to corporate influencers. In this case, I was showing how a question posted to StackOverflow will show up in the Microsoft Teams interface using the Connector.

Our internal concerns are:

- What account is used in the connector? -- The Team owner logs the
  connector into a StackOverflow account.
- Is this account personal or
  managed by the organization? -- By default it is my personal account,
  but StackOverflow has an Enterprise plan.
- Where are questions stored that appear in a Team? -- Questions are
  posted to the Team's persistent chat and are stored with the chat
  data.

Hope this clarifies why this odd question is here. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will my question show up in Microsoft Teams stack overflow connector?

The answer is yes.

You need install the Stack Overflow App to your Microsoft Teams, then you can connect to Stack Overflow with your SO account.

After logging, you can subscribe to the tags you care about, then you will receive following message:

[image]

If the tag you added to the your question is in your tag subscription list, you can see your question in Microsoft Teams, but you could just subscribe to the list of your personal questions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I posted the question while doing a demo of the connector. I should have noted that it was not a real question.